# Create a std::string with fixed data location

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files

Currently I have this going on:

```
struct HashItem {
    uint32_t Value;
    char Key;

    uint32_t GetSize() {
        return 4 + GetKey().size();
    }

    void SetKey(std::string &Key) {
        memcpy(&(this->Key), Key.c_str(), Key.size());
    }
    std::string GetKey() {
        return std::string(&Key);
    }

    static HashItem* Cast(void* p) {
        return reinterpret_cast<HashItem*>(p);
    }
};
```

That struct is meant to be an interpretation of a pointer location in a MMF. At the start of it, I have a hash table and right after it are those HashItems in series. I was wondering though if it was possible to create an std::string with a fixed char*(pointing to where the char Key currently is) for where it keeps the actual data?

That memory is manually managed anyway and having a string field instead of a char field would be more convenient.

Comment: `std::string` can be so much more than a constant string literal - so generally the answer is no. Why not use a pointer where a pointer is due? If you need to actually do string stuffs on your Key (like comparison), you'd have to implement them yourself (i.e. use the standard library for C strings), but you'd avoid the allocation overhead as well.

Comment: Is is a typo, or `Key` is just a single char ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Its a placeholder for retrieving the pointer only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... if it was possible to create an std::string with a fixed char*(pointing to where the char Key currently is) for where it keeps the actual data?

Not really - std::string explicitly and very clearly manages its own memory. You could perhaps hack it with a custom allocator, but I'm inclined to think it would be awful.

If you just want something *like* a `std::string` (ie, having the same operators and public interface) but not owning its own memory, just use a [Boost.String_Ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html), which does what you (seem to) want without hacks.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.
Moreover, when you return an `std::string` in `GetKey()` you're actually copying the string. `std::string` always managers its own memory. One good reason for this is that the pointer can change without any warning and you can never rely on where it is at.
Most implementation of `std::string` have a "short string optimization" where for strings shorter than 16 chars, the memory is actually right there inside the string object as an array. for anything longer, the memory is allocated. This sort of invariant (if len<16 pointer is A else pointer is B) cannot be maintained if the pointer can come from outside.